# What is Raiden's car based on? (if any?)

Tags: metal-gear-rising

[image]

All I can find is this picture in a clear enough quality to make out any design choices.

Comment: "*Raiden: I knew the risks when I decided to go through with this. Besides, the car was mine. Maverick sold it to me. It's not meant for private use; it was made for ops like this.*" - https://metalgear.fandom.com/wiki/Metal_Gear_Rising:_Revengeance_radio_conversations

Comment: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/metalgearsolid/comments/sgailc/what_is_raidens_car_based_of_off/): (looks a bit like maserrati granturismo)